# I want to convert a text file into one JSON string using jq

Tags: command-line, jq

I have a text file, I want to make it into a single JSON string with quotes and \n, ideally from the command line. I don't want multiple strings, or dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat ./my-input-file | jq -R --slurp . > ./my-output.json
```

Comment: No need to `cat`, just do `jq -Rs . input.txt > output.json`